# Getting a count of objects in a queryset in Django

Tags: python, django, count, django-queryset

How can I add a field for the count of objects in a database. I have the following models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Contest(models.Model);
    name = models.CharField()

class Votes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    contest = models.ForeignKey(Contest)
    comment = models.TextField()
```

To find the votes for contestA I am using the following query in my view

```
current_vote = Item.objects.filter(votes__contest=contestA)
```

This returns a queryset with all of the votes individually but I want to get the count votes for each item, anyone know how I can do that? thanks

Answer (score 202, accepted):

To get the number of votes for a specific item, you would use:

```
vote_count = Item.objects.filter(votes__contest=contestA).count()
```

If you wanted a break down of the distribution of votes in a particular contest, I would do something like the following:

```
contest = Contest.objects.get(pk=contest_id)
votes   = contest.votes_set.select_related()

vote_counts = {}

for vote in votes:
  if not vote_counts.has_key(vote.item.id):
    vote_counts[vote.item.id] = {
      'item': vote.item,
      'count': 0
    }

  vote_counts[vote.item.id]['count'] += 1
```

This will create dictionary that maps items to number of votes. Not the only way to do this, but it's pretty light on database hits, so will run pretty quickly.

Comment: for anyone interested - `has_key` was removed in Python 3:  
You can update it to use the `in` operator instead.  

**Example:**. 

`if vote.item.id not in vote_counts:  
       vote_counts[vote.item.id] = {
      'item': vote.item,
      'count': 0
    }`

Answer (score 26):

Another way of doing this would be using [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation/). You should be able to achieve a similar result using a single query. Such as this:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Item.objects.values("contest").annotate(Count("id"))
```

I did not test this specific query, but this should output a count of the items for each value in contests as a dictionary.

Comment: This is still confusing to me. If you annotate on a queryset, you're counting the number of id's belonging to each object, which is obviously 1. So how is that helpful?

Comment: Yes, if you were counting `contest` on the Contest model that would be the case. However, in this case we are aggregating on `Item` which have unique contests.

Comment: What if the count for two objects are same and then we have to sort them based on some other condition. Then how to do that?

Comment: @Tarun you can add values in the annotate, just make sure you do not try to add items that get aggregated during the annotation. Since it returns a queryset all the usual sort functions still apply `.order_by('some_value')`.

Answer (score 2):

Use related name to count votes for a specific contest

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Contest(models.Model);
    name = models.CharField()

class Votes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    contest = models.ForeignKey(Contest, related_name="contest_votes")
    comment = models.TextField()

>>> comments = Contest.objects.get(id=contest_id).contest_votes.count()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**len()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) to get **the count of contestA's votes**:

```py
current_vote = len(Item.objects.filter(votes__contest=contestA))
```

Actually, `len()` is used with [**select_for_update()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) as shown below:

```py
current_vote = len(Item.objects.select_for_update().filter(votes__contest=contestA))
```

Because `select_for_update()` doesn't work with `count()` as shown below:

```py
current_vote = Item.objects.select_for_update().filter(votes__contest=contestA).count()
```

You can see [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74842206/are-there-any-other-cases-which-select-for-update-doesnt-work-but-works-wit/74853691#74853691) explaning about `select_for_update()` with `count()` or `len()`.