# Graphene-Django - how to pass an argument from Query to class DjangoObjectType

Tags: django, graphql, arguments, graphene-django

First of all, thanks ! it has been 1 year without asking question as I always found an answer. You're a tremendous help.

Today, I do have a question I cannot sort out myself.
Please, I hope you would be kind enough to help me on the matter.

*Context:* I work on a project with Django framework, and I have some dynamic pages made with react.js. The API I'm using in between is graphQL based. Apollo for the client, graphene-django for the back end.

I want to do a dynamic pages made from a GraphQL query having a set (a declared field in the class DjangoObjectType made from a Django query), and I want to be able to filter dynamically the parent with a argument A, and the set with argument B. My problem is how to find a way to pass the argument B to the set to filter it.

The graphQL I would achieved based on graphQL documentation

```
query DistributionHisto
(
  $id:ID,
  $limit:Int
)
{
  distributionHisto(id:$id)
  {
    id,
    historical(limit:$limit)
    {
       id,
       date,
       histo
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't understand how to pass (limit:$limit) to my set in the back end.

Here my schema.py

```
import graphene
from graphene_django.types import DjangoObjectType

class DistributionType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = DistributionTuple

    historical = graphene.List(HistoricalTimeSeriesType)

    def resolve_historical(self, info):
        return HistoricalTimeSeries.objects.filter(
            distribution_tuple_id=self.id
            ).order_by('date')[:2]

class Query(object):
    distribution_histo = graphene.List(
        graphene.NonNull(DistributionType),
        id=graphene.ID(),
        limit=graphene.Int()
        )

    def resolve_distribution_histo(
            self, info, id=None, limit=None):
        filter_q1 = {'id': id} if id else {}
        return DistributionTuple.objects.filter(**filter_q1)
```

I have tried few things, but I didn't find a way to make it to work so far.

At the moment, as you see, the arg "limit" reaches a dead end in def resolve*, where ideally, it would be pass up to the class DistributionSetHistoType where it would replace the slice [:2] by [:limit] in resolve_distribution_slice_set()

I hope I have been clear, please let me know if it's not the case.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

This topic called `pagination`.

1. [**front end seletion**](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/core-api/#the-fetchmore-function)

```
const { loading, error, data, fetchMore } = useQuery(GET_ITEMS, {
  variables: {
    offset: 0,
    limit: 10
  },
});
```

2. [**backend selction**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439901/getting-a-count-of-objects-in-a-queryset-in-django)

- the number `10` in `.count(10)` represent the first 10 elements in the array

```
DistributionTuple.objects.filter(**filter_q1).count(10)
```