# How to count a filtered result in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have managed to create a QuerySet of what I want so far, but I am unable to include the `.count ()` statement in it. I do know that I can use `len (students)`, but I would like to stick to the Django ORM.

```
student_count = Student.objects.filter(last_online__range=[last week, this week])
```

How do I do that?

Comment: why `Student.objects.filter(last_online__range=[last week, this week]).count()` is not working?

Comment: `Student.objects.filter(last_online__range=[last week, this week]).count()` doesn't work?

Comment: Could be duplicate/related :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439901/getting-a-count-of-objects-in-a-queryset-in-django

Comment: `.count()` at the end does work. You can add it as the answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @uber answer added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `count()`

```
Student.objects.filter(last_online__range=[last week, this week]).count()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `aggregate()` to count, like this:

```
student_count = Student.objects.filter(last_online__range=[last week, this week]).aggregate(Count('MODEL_FILE'))
```

The function of Django's aggregate() method is to perform statistical calculations on a set of values (such as a field of the queryset) and return the statistical calculation results in a dictionary (Dict) format.